# Tabbed Page Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion, tabbedpage

I'm using syncfusion schedule, I used tabbed page to show 2 different daily schedules:

```
MainPage = new TabbedPage{
  Children =
  {
      new DailyView(),
      new DailyViewMaterials()
  }
};
```

the two pages DailyView and DailyViewMaterials have the same style: 2 labels above and then a synycfusion schedule but the schedules have different data source, and different appointments.

When I run the project and click on an appointment it will show a frame that contains the appointment details. First it works fine but when I switch to the second page, then switch back to the first page and click on an appointment it fires the appointmentClicked Event of the second schedule, any solution?

EDIT:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:eAgenda1"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:eAgenda1.ViewModels;assembly=eAgenda1"
         xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:eAgenda1.Models;assembly=eAgenda1"
         xmlns:ActivitiesDailySchedule="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms"
         x:Class="eAgenda1.DailyView"
         Title="Activities"
         BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
      <ViewModels:ActivitiesViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Padding>
     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"  iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" Android="0"  WinPhone="0" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
<StackLayout x:Name ="acitivitiesMainStack"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<Label x:Name="dateLabel"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       FontSize="Large"/>
<Label x:Name="weekLabel"
       HorizontalOptions="End"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
<ActivitiesDailySchedule:SfSchedule x:Name="activitiesSchedule"
                          BackgroundColor="White"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          ScheduleView="DayView"
                          ShowAppointmentsInline="True"
                          DataSource="{Binding ActivitiesCollection}"
                         ScheduleCellTapped="ActivitiesSchedule_CellTapped">
</ActivitiesDailySchedule:SfSchedule>
<Frame x:Name="appointmentDetailsFrame"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       OutlineColor="Accent"
       IsVisible="False">
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Label x:Name="subjectLabel"
          FontSize="Large"/>
        <Label x:Name="descriptionLabel"
               FontSize="Medium"/>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <Label x:Name="typeLabel"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
               FontSize="Medium"/>
        <Label x:Name="timeLabel"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
               FontSize="Small"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="cancelButton"
            Text="OK"
            Clicked="CancelClicked"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

and the code behind:

```
 void CancelClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        appointmentDetailsFrame.IsVisible = false;
        activitiesSchedule.IsVisible = true;
    }
    void ActivitiesSchedule_CellTapped(object sender, ScheduleTappedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.selectedAppointment != null)
        {    
            activitiesSchedule.IsVisible = false;
            appointmentDetailsFrame.IsVisible = true;
            var selectedAppointment = (Activity)args.selectedAppointment;
            typeLabel.Text = selectedAppointment.Type;
            subjectLabel.Text = selectedAppointment.Subject;
            descriptionLabel.Text = selectedAppointment.Description;
            timeLabel.Text = selectedAppointment.Time;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(selectedAppointment.Type);
        }

        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No activities");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Some DataContext errors ?

Comment: It doesn't gives me an error or exception, and I switched the place like:

    MainPage = new TabbedPage{
  Children =
  {
      new DailyViewMaterials(),
      new DailyView()
  }
}; always the first page don't show  the cell content on tap  when I switch to the second and switch back to the first

Comment: Can you please show some Code of `DailyView` ?

Comment: @Mireille, issue is still there?